# Angular 2 throwing error: Outlet is not activated

Tags: angular, angular2-router3

I have set up my app so that I have a `Recipe Book` which has a list of `Recipies` which when I click on a Recipe it then shows the `Recipe Details` in a nested route. This then also has a button that when clicked loads the ingredients in a nested route inside the `Recipes Details`.

So far the routing seems to work, except when I try to navigate to another `Recipe`. If the `Ingredients` tray(route) is active then it will change Recipe and collapse the `Ingredients` Route, If I then try and navigate (without opening the Ingredients) I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Outlet is not activated
Error: Outlet is not activated
```

It looks like I the router needs `Ingredients` to be active or else it doesn't understand the nested route. Thats my take on it but not sure how to fix it or when I went wrong.

**single-recipe-book-page.component.html**

```
<app-tray class="recipe-list">
    <app-recipe-list [recipe]="recipe"></app-recipe-list>
</app-tray>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**recipe-detail.component.html**

```
<app-tray class="recipe">
    The routing has worked and loaded recipe.
</app-tray>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**ingredients-list.component.html**

```
<app-tray class="ingredients-list">
    Recipe Ingredients have loaded.
</app-tray>
```

**app.routes.ts** (updated)

```
export const routerConfig : Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'recipe-books',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id', component: SingleRecipeBookPageComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'recipes',
            children: [
              { path: ':id', component: RecipeDetailComponent,
                children: [
                  { path: '', component: IngredientsListComponent },
                  { path: 'ingredients', component: IngredientsListComponent }
                ]
              },
              { path: 'new', component: IngredientsListComponent },
              { path: '', component: RecipeDetailComponent }
            ]
          },
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'recipes', pathMatch: 'full' }
        ]
      },
      { path: '', component: RecipeBooksPageComponent }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'ingredients', component: IngredientsComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'recipe-books', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'recipe-books', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Comment: What are these routes supposed to do?

Comment: You didn't add the `pathMatch: 'full'` to 2 empty path child routes. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: Even if they have a component should I still add `pathMatch: full`?

Comment: Yes. `pathMatch: 'full'` should added to every `{ path: '' ...}` route that doesn't have child routes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This route is invalid and you should get an error for it.

```
{ path: '' },
```

A route either needs to have a `component`, a `redirectTo`, or `children`.

If an empty path route has no children it also should have `pathMatch: 'full'`.

I guess what you want is

```
{ path: '', component: DummyComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
```

Where `DummyComponent` is a component with an empty view.
You can reuse the same `DummyComponent` for all these paths.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity, I have searched the heck out of the internet around this issue and so far missed that one important point, infact in tutorials I have followed, they use `{ path: '' }` so it's been very confusing whilst trying to learn.

Comment: Could you solve all issues or is there still something not working as expected?

Comment: Updated my code above with new routing. 
I can now navigate between `Recipe-books>Single Recipe>Ingredients`  no outlet error. But now if I visit the `Recipe 1`, the Ingredients are not show(This is correct it should only show when I click ingredients button and it goes to `recipe-books/1/recipe/1/notes`) if I click the button the ingredients show. Perfect! Then I click on the `Recipe 2` (ingredients still active) I get `Recipe 2` but with `Recipe 1` Ingredients. If I click the Ingredients button now `Recipe 2s` ingredients load. Any ideas where I could be going wrong?

Comment: Can you please try to reproduce in a button. In Plunker editor the `[ New | V ]` button provides a ready-to-use Angular 2 TS template. If you run into issues just add a comment and I try to help.

Comment: I'll have a go and see if I can get a plunker working.

Comment: I couldn't get a build working in plunker, but after some tinkeringI was able to figure it out. I had really just missed how empty paths need to be treated and you covered that clearly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can block component creation with `runGuardsAndResolvers: () => false`. No DummyComponent needed :-)

Comment: @Simon_Weaver interesting. Never saw that mentioned, but haven't worked with Angular in a while.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I added a full answer to this question but wanted to ping you too. Seems like this is working ok now - it’s one of those massively annoying error messages when you almost get rid of it then it reappears!  One github issue had discussion of ‘never’ as an option which would make a lot of sense here but that didn’t get added. But forcing false is working for me :)

Answer (score 4):

TLDR; answer :

```
{
      path: ':question',
      runGuardsAndResolvers: GUARDS_RESOLVERS_DISABLED   // blocks component creation
}
```

Where `GUARDS_RESOLVERS_DISABLED` is a global function (to avoid issues with AOT).

```
 export function GUARDS_RESOLVERS_DISABLED() { return false; }
```

---

There's a [new feature](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/26861) in Angular router that sounds related to this problem, but isn't - as far as I can tell - a direct solution for it. The new option is `runGuardsAndResolvers = 'pathParamsChange'` and it affects when Angular checks guards and resolvers - and crucially whether it runs this outlet check.

So before I found the new option:

- I was stepping through into angular code - and the actual error occurs here (highlighted I n red) at `context.outlet.component` (where `component` is a getter that throws).

[image]

- So to fix I'd just need to make `shouldRun == false` somehow.
- And `shouldRun` is simply `shouldRunGuardsAndResolvers(...)` so if that can be made to return false then it won't try to create a component in the 'wrong' place.

So the solution is quite simple:

```
 {
        path: 'contactus',
        component: ContactUsComponent,

        children: [
            {
                path: 'topics',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            
            {
                path: 'faq',
                component: FaqPanelComponent
            },
            
            { 
                path: 'test',
                component: ContactusTopicListComponent
            },
            {
                path: ':category',
                
                children: 
                [
                    {
                        path: ':question',
                        runGuardsAndResolvers: () => false   // blocks component creation
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

Currently `runGuardsAndResolvers` has quite a [few options](https://angular.io/api/router/RunGuardsAndResolvers), but the one I'm using just always returns `false` which is equivalent to `never` which really ought to be made into an option. But that's how I found out about the new router features :-)

Also if you have two levels you need to put this at both (or possibly just the highest) level:

```
        {
            path: ':category',
            runGuardsAndResolvers: () => false,
            
            children: 
            [
                {
                    path: ':question',
                    runGuardsAndResolvers: () => false
                }
            ]
        }
```

Further reading on resolvers: https://blog.angularindepth.com/new-in-angular-v7-1-updates-to-the-router-fd67d526ad05

---

**Edit:** To make this work properly with AOT / Angular 9/10+ you can create a global function to avoid the issue mentioned by Sunil.

```
export function GUARDS_RESOLVERS_DISABLED() { return false; }
```

Then use this syntax

```
runGuardsAndResolvers: GUARDS_RESOLVERS_DISABLED
```

Comment: if I am using  runGuardsAndResolvers: () => false for development it is working fine, but for production it is throwing error while compiling                                                                      ERROR in Error during template compile of 'ɵ0'
  Function expressions are not supported in decorators
    Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.
src/app/app-routing.module.ts(128,31): Error during template compile of 'ɵ1'
  Function expressions are not supported in decorators
    Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.

Comment: did you try that with --prod

Comment: @sunil yes I’m using this in an aot production site

Comment: I am facing issue with that, can you share code snippet for routing module

Answer (score 3):

This might help someone else.

I was getting this error. I have checked all my defined `routes` in my route file,
the `path` and `components` are defined correctly.

The reason of getting this error was that I forgot to add reference of my `service` in `app.module.ts` which was being used in one of my component to get data from `RestApi`.

So, always add service reference in app.module.ts in `providers` section, immediately after creating service.

```
imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   HttpModule,
   ......
 ],

providers: [
    AuthService, 
    ........ // Here, service reference
]
```

Comment: omg same thing happened to me, thanks for saving me some more extra wasted time for such a blocker!

Answer (score 0):

For production **runGuardsAndResolvers: () =>** is not working.
Angular has new feature for **runGuardsAndResolvers**.

For working you can try **runGuardsAndResolvers: "pathParamsChange"**
Tested in Angular 8 works fine.