# Router-outlet activating unexpectedly in wrong place

Tags: angular, router

I have a child control that I want to activate inside a `mat-tab-group` control (I don't want to use `mat-nav` because I want the animations provided by `mat-tab-group` - and it's just easier to let the tab control handle component creation.

However my child route is activating in multiple places.

```
<mat-tab-group>

    <mat-tab label="Animals">

        <ng-component *ngIf="showCats">
            Cats
        </ng-component>

        <ng-component *ngIf="!showCats">
            Dogs
        </ng-component>

    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="FAQ">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-tab>

</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: May also be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413133/angular-2-throwing-error-outlet-is-not-activated/54849133#54849133

Answer (score 1):

#### This can occur if you put `ng-component` instead of `ng-container`

Very easy mistake to make - but the router will consider `ng-component` as some special type of child and automatically create a `router-outlet` inside it.

The solution is simple - use `ng-container`

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="showCats">CATS</ng-container>
```

Comment: I'm not clear of the exact mechanism that causes this automatic `router-outlet` - if anyone knows please comment!